# Get pandas on android

Tags: android, python, pandas

I'm trying to write some scripts to run on my android device. In my python coding I have come to rely quite a bit on [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to organize my data.

I'm curios how I can get pandas on my android phone - in my Google queries I have come across [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android), which seem relevant, but I don't understand how I can use this to get pandas BEFORE I actually want to package my script for distribution.

Also, quite obviously the pandas libs aren't in the GooglePlay store.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found so far, looks like your best bet is QPython3. It is not in the Play Store, you have to sideload it. It supports packages. I have to say it does not seem very stable. I also thougt of trying some quick experiments with pandas, scikit-learn, etc. on Android, but the whole experience is kind of slow and distracting, no matter which tools I try. Even online IDEs / scripting playgrounds look more promising. I keep an eye open for a good offline option though.